# Access denied using psexec when connect to remote server

Tags: remote-access, psexec

I use latest version of PsExec, and execute Command Prompt as Run as Administrator. 
We use PsExec v2.11

```
MY_MACHINE is on MY_DOMAIN domain.
REMOTE_SERVER is on OTHER_DOMAIN domain.
user_partner is on DOMAIN_PARTNER.NET.
```

For execute a simple Server connectivity test (for eg. From my machine MY_MACHINE to REMOTE_SERVER server)

```
C:\Tests\GRMDeployment\Tools>PsExec \\REMOTE_SERVER.OTHER_DOMAIN.local -u OTHER_DOMAIN\USER_FOR_TFS -p **PASS** cmd.exe /v /c echo ^%computername^%

PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


REMOTE_SERVER
cmd.exe exited on REMOTE_SERVER.OTHER_DOMAIN.local with error code 0.
```

Another partner in another domain, it gets Accesss denied error.

The user to log into the machine is DOMAIN_PARTNER\user_partner.

```
COMPUTERNAME=WS001S90-01-JEN
USERDNSDOMAIN=DOMAIN_PARTNER.NET
USERDOMAIN=DOMAIN_PARTNER
USERNAME=user_partner
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\user_partner
```

I checked the ports used by PSExec, 445 and 135, and both are open on the REMOTE_SERVER.OTHER_DOMAIN.local  machine:

```
nc -z REMOTE_SERVER.OTHER_DOMAIN.local 445
Connection to REMOTE_SERVER.OTHER_DOMAIN.local port 445 [tcp/microsoft-ds] succeeded!

nc -z REMOTE_SERVER.OTHER_DOMAIN.local 135
Connection to REMOTE_SERVER.OTHER_DOMAIN.local port 135 [tcp/epmap] succeeded!
```

The directory is accessible from Explorer:

```
\\REMOTE_SERVER.OTHER_DOMAIN.local\SharedFolder
```

I get Access is Denied error, also with Admin user.

```
PsExec \\REMOTE_SERVER.OTHER_DOMAIN.local -u OTHER_DOMAIN\TFSADMIN -p xxxxx cmd.exe /v /c echo ^%computername^%
```

I try Add a Windows credential.

```
Internet or network address: REMOTE_SERVER.OTHER_DOMAIN.local
User Name: OTHER_DOMAIN\USER_FOR_TFS
Password: **PASS**
```

And I get the same error.

Then, I try this:

```
C:\Users\user_partner>net user administrator /enable:yes
The command completed successfully.


C:\Users\user_partner>PsExec \\REMOTE_SERVER.OTHER_DOMAIN.local -u OTHER_DOMAIN\USER_FOR_TFS -p xxxxxx cmd.exe /v /c echo ^%computername^%

PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Couldn't access REMOTE_SERVER.OTHER_DOMAIN.local:
Access is denied.
```

Other test:

```
C:\Users\user_partner>PsExec \\REMOTE_SERVER -u OTHER_DOMAIN\USER_FOR_TFS -p **PASS** cmd.exe /v /c echo ^%computername^%

PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Couldn't access REMOTE_SERVER:
The network path was not found.
```

Other test, using the ip, I get Access denied:

```
C:\Users\user_partner>PsExec \\10.254.6.40 -u OTHER_DOMAIN\USER_FOR_TFS -p **PASS** cmd.exe /v /c echo ^%computername^%

PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Couldn't access 10.254.6.40:
Access is denied.
```

Other test

```
runas /user:OTHER_DOMAIN\USER_FOR_TFS cmd 

PsExec \\REMOTE_SERVER.OTHER_DOMAIN.local -u OTHER_DOMAIN\USER_FOR_TFS -p **PASS** cmd.exe /v /c echo ^%computername^%
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

try the following:

1. try to disable UAC on the target machine - TRY THIS FIRST!
2. check if you can access \admin$ share on the target machine
3. try to use a domain user and not a local user. this domain user must
   be admin on the target machine
4. try to add the name and password to credentials cache with `cmdkey` before using
   psexec

using cmdkey:

```
cmdkey.exe /add:MACHINE_NAME /user:MACHINE_NAME\Administrator /pass:PASSWORD
psexec.exe \\MACHINE_NAME cmd
cmdkey.exe /delete:MACHINE_NAME
```

5. try to [disbale uac for remote users](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/951016) by running this on the **target machine**

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```